# Why is table not responsive under 768px and why is footer not at the bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

when you make the screen smaller than 768px the table is not responsive, neither the navigation bar and footer is at the page bottom.
Is it okay if we only add span class(col-*) to one of the td in one of the rows of table.

```css
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}


/*section heading style*/

section h1 {
    display: none;
}


/*aside styles*/

aside .panel-default>.panel-heading {
    color: #7386D5;
    margin: 0;
}

.pager li a {
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.nav-stacked li a {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}


/*footer Styles*/

footer {
    background: #efefef;
    height: 49px;
    line-height: 49px;
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
}

footer p {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #555;
}


/*main section styles*/

main {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Blog</title>
    <!--Link to StyleSheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Blog</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></span> About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span> Archives</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <section>
        <h1>Blog Posts</h1>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <main class="col-md-9">
                    <!-- Responsive Bootstrap Table -->
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Row</th>
                                <th>First Name</th>
                                <th>Last Name</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Biography</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>John</td>
                                <td>Carter</td>
                                <td>johncarter@mail.com</td>
                                <td class="col-md-6 col-xs-3 col-sm-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet assumenda atque delectus quis itaque cumque neque iste, ullam dolorem quas. Facere voluptate architecto dolorum totam quo doloribus animi velit molestias.</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>Peter</td>
                                <td>Parker</td>
                                <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
                                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas soluta officiis non, adipisci quaerat doloremque molestiae delectus aspernatur sequi consectetur architecto quas, error magnam nemo, facere voluptatem neque illum repellat!</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>John</td>
                                <td>Rambo</td>
                                <td>johnrambo@mail.com</td>
                                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem modi dignissimos blanditiis doloribus porro labore voluptatem voluptate ipsa nesciunt, repudiandae officiis tempora, veniam, facilis unde, incidunt ipsum beatae! Quae, nulla!</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>4</td>
                                <td>John</td>
                                <td>Doe</td>
                                <td>johndoe@mail.com</td>
                                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid ratione cupiditate architecto assumenda esse accusantium vitae, delectus necessitatibus ea itaque eveniet, totam alias, fuga ut! Saepe culpa fugit, optio sit?</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>                    
                </div>
                </main>
                <!-- Blog post section ends here -->
                <aside class="col-md-3">
                    <nav class="panel panel-default">
                        <h3 class="panel-heading">Blog Sidebar</h3>
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked panel-body">
                            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#collapse-target" data-toggle="collapse">Archives <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul id="collapse-target" class="collapse nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                                    <li><a href="#">January <span class="badge">2</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">February <span class="badge">42</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">March <span class="badge">23</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">April <span class="badge">1</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">May <span class="badge">12</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">June <span class="badge">43</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">July <span class="badge">32</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">August  <span class="badge">122</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">September <span class="badge">76</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">October <span class="badge">76</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">November <span class="badge">56</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">December <span class="badge">98</span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </aside>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <footer>
        <p><small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copyright-mark"></span> Copyright 2017 programmers inc.</small></p>
    </footer>    
    <!--Link to Javascript-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../javascript/scripts1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#tables-responsive), this is expected behavior.

> Create responsive tables by wrapping any .table in .table-responsive to make them scroll horizontally on small devices (under 768px). When viewing on anything larger than 768px wide, you will not see any difference in these tables.

The table will scroll horizontally on small devices, not collapse in any way.

---

Regarding your footer, it *is* at the bottom. It's just that there isn't enough content on your page to push it all the way down to the bottom of the screen. In order to ensure the footer is always at the bottom, take a look at Bootstrap's [Sticky Footer](https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/sticky-footer-navbar.html) example. A quick Google Search for that should lead you to several other solutions as well. Pick any one.

If you want to hide or show certain elements based on the screen size, take a look at the documentation for [Responsive Utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#responsive-utilities). For example, adding the class `.hidden-md` to certain rows should hide them on medium sized devices. The class `.visible-lg` will make an element visible only on large screens.

Comment: is there any way in bootstrap to make it responsive and why is footer not at the bottom

Comment: The footer is at the bottom. Its just that there isn't enough content on your page to push it all the way to the bottom of the page. What you need is to Google around for `Sticky Footers` and implement that, assuming that you want the footer to always stick to the bottom of the screen, regardless of the amount of content on the page.